# jQuery cookie working for all pages except homepage

Tags: jquery, wordpress, cookies, jquery-cookie

I've been trying to work this out, but I can't pinpoint the problem - I'm using jQuery cookie to display a cookie consent message here:

http://www.generatinggenius.org.uk/programmes/

But I can't get it to work on the homepage:

http://www.generatinggenius.org.uk/

Here's my jQuery code, can anyone see the problem?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { /* WORDPRESS-READY NOCONFLICT MODE!!! */
    // Cookie / ppolicy consent
    var cookie = $.cookie('accept_pp');
    $('#cconsent #accept').click(function() {
        $.cookie('accept_pp', 'yes', { expires: 14, path: '/' }); // expires in 14 days, valid throughout site
        $('#cconsent').slideUp('medium');
    });
    if(cookie == 'yes') {
        // PP accepted
    } else {
        $('#cconsent').delay(500).slideDown('slow');
    }
    // $.removeCookie('accept_pp', { path: '/' });
});
```

Comment: How are you enqueuing the script?

Comment: Try fixing the errors that appear in your browser's console

Comment: Hi both, enqueuing the script like so: `<script defer src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/osu/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
 <script defer src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/js/osu/osu-functions.js"></script>` and I'm assuming the error in `plugins.min.js` is what's causing the problem, but as this is a theme, I'm unsure where or how to fix without destroying the theme...